# Add item from finder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, finder

I have a table with the classic + - buttons underneath it. (on mac)
I want to press the + button, and open a little finder to select a file, to add it on the table.

How can I do that?
I searched the developer reference, but didn't find it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`NSOpenPanel`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

For a guide on dealing with files and using open panels, see the [Application File Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AppFileMgmt/Tasks/UsingAnOpenPanel.html) guide.

For instance:

```
- (IBAction)addFile:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger result;
    NSArray *fileTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"html"];
    NSOpenPanel *oPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    [oPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
    [oPanel setDirectory:NSHomeDirectory()];
    [oPanel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
    result = [oPanel runModal];

    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        for (NSURL *fileURL in [oPanel URLs]) {
            // do something with fileURL
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another example using a sheet:

```
- (IBAction)addFile:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *fileTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"html"];
    NSOpenPanel *oPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    [oPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
    [oPanel setDirectory:NSHomeDirectory()];
    [oPanel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
    [oPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:[self window]
        completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
            for (NSURL *fileURL in [oPanel URLs]) {
                // do something with fileURL
            }
        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: thanks, but this one makes a new window. I would like the one that slides from the top.. You know what I mean? I don't know what's it called.

Comment: @pvinis You want a sheet, then. Instead of `-runModal`, use `– beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:`.

Comment: @pvinis I’ve edited the answer and included an example using a sheet.